# increase site speed by increasing memory limit?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, memory, xampp

I am using an ubuntu server : 512MB ram / 1 CPU
I want to increase my wordpress site speed by adjusting php,mysql memory limits to be suitable with my server specification.
I am using xampp server.

Comment: Be more specific - do you want to know what good settings for your setup are, do you want to know how to actually change those settings? What is it you want to do?

Comment: @mtsvetkov I want to know how to adjust php memory limits to be suitable for 512MB ram. also the same thing for Mysql

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call an override function to change memory limit localy on the application just call this at the top of your php file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); //change 64M to whatever you like...
```

OR change it globaly in php.ini (in xampp located in '\xampp\php\php.ini'):

```
memory_limit = 8M // search for this "memory_limit" and adjust it by your needs.
```

After that restart apache...

- But in my experience memory load problems are more connected with execution of MySQL queries then running php scripts alone. CPU load also, almost always connected with badly written queries.

Also 512mb is realy low ammount for a serious web server.

Comment: what do you think if i set it to 265M ? is that suitable or will be very high ?

Comment: 128MB would be more then enough for most CMS scripts... I had some problems with 64mb memory limit when I started some HTML parsers I was wirting even in that case 128mb solved it permanently.

Comment: @ossama - you want the memory value to be the _smallest_ that will let your application run. Think of it in terms of how many concurrent users you want to handle at the same time - in a 512M system, you'll only be able to handle one at a time, since 2 * 256M would leave zero memory left for any other processes. Well written systems PHP should fit into 20-32M in my view - more than that and you should improve your design.